# Laravel 4 - error 405 on RESTful DELETE

Tags: http, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I've a route defined as below:

```
Route::resource('api/invoice', 'InvoiceController');
```

In my controller I have a `function destroy($id)`

When sending a `DELETE` request to `/api/invoice` with an `id: 2` as parameter and I get a 405 error message back.
I tried accessing this route from Postman and from a javascript code directly, without success...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your javascript code that you are calling the route from?

Comment: It is an angularjs http call: $http.delete(this.config.BASE_API_URL+'/invoice', {'id': '2'}).success(function(data) {
                if (data.code = 1) {
                    console.log("success");
                } else {
                    console.log("validation error");
                }
            });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said `I get a 405 error` and that is because of wrong `HTTP Method`, in your `Resource Controller` you have the `destroy` method and in this case this method is accessible using a `DELETE` request. So make sure you are sending a `DELETE` request for this.

You may run the following command from your terminal/command prompt:

```
php artisan routes
```

It'll output the routes with their names and `URL` so find the route and check the request method and `URL` to access that method. Check [HTTP Error 405 Method not allowed](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html) for more information. If you are using `JavaScript/AJAX` to invoke the `destroy` method then, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23899545/741747).

Comment: php artisan routes, returns the list of rout where I have: DELETE api/invoice/{invoice} as expected. As I said, I tried both using js and postman chrome ext which creates a HTTP DELETE request.

Comment: Ok found the issue... really stupid, my url was incorrect: /api/invoice?id=1 instead of /api/invoice/1. Never work after midnight after a full workday ;-) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @LEM01, You are welcome and btw, I work at midnight, 12am - 6am is the best time for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

405 error was returned because the request URL wasn't matching the DELETE URI:

Expected destroy URI: DELETE api/invoice/{invoice}
Used destroy URI: DELETE api/invoice?id=1

As simple as that...