# Laravel delete with jQuery data model issue

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.1

I'm using jQuery modal box for delete function. But I'm getting this error when clicking yes button on modal box

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Here is my view which I load the data modal popup

```
<a data-toggle='modal' 
   data-target='#delete-user-warning-data-{{ $company1->id}}' href="{{url('delete-warning', $company1->id)}}">
    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['delete-warning', $company1->id],'class' => 'form-del']) !!}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dadnger" aria-label="Center Align" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </button>
    {{--<button type="submit" id="del" class="btn"--}}
    {{--onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to permnently delete the license code? If the code is  currently being used by a book, it will be in in-accessible until the  user entries a new code.')">--}}
    {{--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span>--}}
    {{--</button>--}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</a>

<!-- DELETE -->
<div class="modal fade" id="delete-user-warning-data-{{ $company1->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure you want to delete ?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="center-block text-center">{{ $company1->id}}</p>
                <div class="prompt-center-area">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="closeModel();">No</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Yes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the route

```
Route::delete('delete-warning/{id}', ['as'    => 'delete-warning', 'uses'  => 'CodesController@destroy']);
```

and this is my controller for delete function

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    try{
          $Code = Codes::findOrFail($id);

    $Code->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }catch(\Exception $e){

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Please advice me how fix this issue

Comment: check your routes, have a delete type routet there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898349/getting-a-405-method-not-allowed-exception

Comment: @madalinivascu : no jquery data modal

Comment: Please share your JQuery code throwing the error. It's Javascript issue not Laravel.